# Composite function theorem when x goes to infinity

Tags: calculus

I am trying to do the problem of the following kind. Evaluate

$$ \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} e^{f(x)} $$

where $f(x)$ is some polynomial. Now exponential and polynomial functions are continuous, so, if the $ x \to a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ then, I can use composite function theorem here.If, we know that $f(x)$ is continuous at $L$ and

$$ \lim \limits_{x \to a} g(x) = L $$

then, it follows from composite function theorem that

$$ \lim \limits_{x \to a} f(g(x)) = f\left( \lim \limits_{x \to a} g(x) \right) = f(L) $$

So, if $x \to a$, then, in my case, I would have done

$$ \lim \limits_{x \to a} e^{f(x)} = e^\left( \lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x)\right) $$

But, $x \to \infty$ in my limit. So, which theorem can I use here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you distinguish between different cases:

Case 1: Suppose $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=L<\infty$

Then you can apply your theorem and you're done.

Case 2: Suppose $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)= \infty$

then given any $N \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $x$ such that $f(x)>N$

Since $e^x>x$ for all $x$, then $e^{f(x)}>f(x)>N$. Hence $\lim_{x \to \infty}e^{f(x)}= \infty$

Ill leave the case where $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)= - \infty$ to you since hopefully you got the idea.

Comment: Case 1 does not really apply to polynomials (except constant $f$, but it's trivial in this case) which always have a $\pm\infty$ limit.